# how to create a gradient effect on half of an image

Tags: css, overlay, gradient

I am trying to create a gradient effect over half of my image, I found this which gives a full gradient overlay effect over my image

```
.tinted-image {
  background: 
    /* top, transparent red */ 
    rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25),
    /* bottom, image */
    url(image.jpg);
}
```

but I was wondering how I can only apply this effect to only half of my image,I searched online but didnt see exactly what i ws looking for, so I decided to post.

By half of my image I mean vertically not horizontally

Us there anyone who has an idea of this

Comment: You probably want two different elements, one of them can be a pseudo-element (before or after).

Comment: hw do i go abt it pls

Comment: Your example does not use a gradient, only a semi-transparent background color. It is very unclear what you are asking about – please consider editing your question to be more clear.

Comment: ok hold, ill show u wat am trying to do

Comment: https://www.chefd.com/ , pls take a look at dat link

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<img class="tinted-image" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"/>
```

CSS

```
.tinted-image {
  width: 150px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(255,0,0,0.5),rgba(255,0,0,0), transparent)  
}
```

And the image as source I would do it this way, just for info.

**edit**: [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Dezain/yjgx77qe/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Multiple backgrounds and suitable color stop in the gradient.

```css
.tinted-image {
  width: 460px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 255, 0, 0) 50%, transparent 50%), url(http://www.fillmurray.com/460/300);
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="tinted-image"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working a example.

Which should be your div containing an image

```
<div class="tinted-image"></div>
```

You CSS

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.tinted-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('http://images.kuoni.co.uk/73/johannesburg-and-pretoria-38330408-1438098667-WideInspirationalPhoto.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

  &:before {
    content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to left bottom,#002f4b,#dc4225);
        opacity: .5; 
      height:100%;
      width:50%;
  }
}
```